# Validate Grand Totals on Master Sheet match to supporting worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I want to implement a validation on the totals on a master sheet.  The different totals should match to the totals from each worksheet in the workbook (supporting documentation).  Below is the code where I have defined variables for the worksheets and Named the ranges of where each total is located.  I want to build the code to do the following:
Does RecAR = ARbal? If Yes, then conditionally format "OK" in Green; If no, then "Difference" and conditionally format in Red
This should be done for all the comparisons like so:

```
    RecAR = ARbal
    RecTB1 = TBbal1
    RecJE1 = JEnb1
    RecPP = PPbal
    RecTB2 = TBbal2
    RecJE2 = JEnb2
```

The master sheet is the "Reconciliation" sheet.  The totals are listed in columns D,E,F,H,I,J and will be on the same row where "Grand Total" is populated in column A.  In this example it is located on Row 15386 but this will vary from month to month.  I would like the validation below the totals on the master reconciliation sheet.

```
    Sub RecValidation()
'Goal is to create a validation check to ensure all data transfered from supporting docs to
'recon template
'
'Set up worksheet variables for supporting tabs
Dim Aged As Worksheet
Dim TB1 As Worksheet
Dim TB2 As Worksheet
Dim JEAR As Worksheet
Dim JEPP As Worksheet

Set Aged = Sheets("Aged AR")
Set TB1 = Sheets("TB 1260 AR")
Set TB2 = Sheets("TB 2255 Prepaid")
Set JEAR = Sheets("JEs 1260 AR")
Set JEPP = Sheets("JEs 2255 Prepaid")

    'Set up Range variables for the grandtotals for each column with amounts on recon template that come from supporting docs
    Dim RecAR As Range
    Dim RecTB1 As Range
    Dim RecJE1 As Range
    Dim RecPP As Range
    Dim RecTB2 As Range
    Dim RecJE2 As Range

    Set RecAR = Columns("A").Find("Grand Total", LookAt:=xlPart).Offset(0, 3)
    Set RecTB1 = RecAR.Offset(0, 1)
    Set RecJE1 = RecAR.Offset(0, 2)
    Set RecPP = RecAR.Offset(0, 4)
    Set RecTB2 = RecAR.Offset(0, 5)
    Set RecJE2 = RecAR.Offset(0, 6)

'Set up Range variables for the grandtotals for each supporting document
Dim ARbal As Range
Dim PPbal As Range
Dim TBbal1 As Range
Dim TBbal2 As Range
Dim JEnb1 As Range
Dim JEnb2 As Range

'The headers may be in a merged cell therefore I'm offsetting a few rows down then using xlDown
'to get to the row with the total.  All supporting documentation will have the totals the next
'row below the last row of data
Set ARbal = Aged.Cells.Find("Charges", LookAt:=xlPart).Offset(5, 0).End(xlDown)
Set PPbal = Aged.Cells.Find("Prepays", LookAt:=xlPart).Offset(5, 0).End(xlDown)
Set TBbal1 = TB1.Cells.Find("Tenant", LookAt:=xlPart).Offset(5, 0).End(xlDown)
Set TBbal2 = TB2.Cells.Find("Tenant", LookAt:=xlPart).Offset(5, 0).End(xlDown)
Set JEnb1 = JEAR.Cells.Find("Net Activity", LookAt:=xlPart).End(xlDown)
Set JEnb2 = JEPP.Cells.Find("Net Activity", LookAt:=xlPart).End(xlDown)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I have my head wrapped around what you are trying to do. My first suggestion would be to set up a loop. I think it could be a lot cleaner that way. In order to set up a loop, you'd want to use an [Enum](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx?bcsi-ac-1b9a071560da4e47=21C52E6C00000005y%20pGNyvy%20iQFlrtWEHkwb1kHdEtAAAAABQAAAFpqOwBQRgAAFAAAAGrkAAA=) that has an [ending](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=160345) to define each of your ranges. Enums will simply act as a mask for our place in the array so that the code will be easier to read, debug, and modify. It would look something like this...

```
Public Enum rangeNames
     AR = 1
     TB1 = 2
     JE1 = 3
     PP = 4
     TB2 = 5
     JE2 = 6
     [_EndPlaceholder] 
     finalValue = [_EndPlaceholder] - 1
End Enum
```

So now you would define both your ranges as a range array. This will become apparent why when we get to the loop. Think of the rangeNames.Xs used here as masks for numbers. `Set recRanges(rangeNames.JE1)` is the same as `Set recRanges(3)`.

```
Dim recRanges() as Range
Dim balRanges() as Range
ReDim recRanges(rangeNames.finalValue)
ReDim balRanges(rangeNames.finalValue)
Set recRanges(rangeNames.AR) = Columns("A").Find("Grand Total", LookAt:=xlPart).Offset(0,3)
Set recRanges(rangeNames.TB1) = recRange(rangeNames.AR).Offset(,1)
Set recRanges(rangeNames.JE1) = recRange(rangeNames.AR).Offset(,2)
Set recRanges(rangeNames.PP) = recRange(rangeNames.AR).Offset(,4)
Set recRanges(rangeNames.TB2) = recRange(rangeNames.AR).Offset(,5)
Set recRanges(rangeNames.JE2) = recRange(rangeNames.AR).Offset(,6)
Set balRanges(rangeNames.AR) = Aged.Cells.Find("Charges", LookAt:=xlPart).Offset(5, 0).End(xlDown)
Set balRanges(rangeNames.PP) = Aged.Cells.Find("Prepays", LookAt:=xlPart).Offset(5, 0).End(xlDown)
Set balRanges(rangeNames.TB1) = TB1.Cells.Find("Tenant", LookAt:=xlPart).Offset(5, 0).End(xlDown)
Set balRanges(rangeNames.TB2) = TB2.Cells.Find("Tenant", LookAt:=xlPart).Offset(5, 0).End(xlDown)
Set balRanges(rangeNames.JE1) = JEAR.Cells.Find("Net Activity", LookAt:=xlPart).End(xlDown)
Set balRanges(rangeNames.JE2) = JEPP.Cells.Find("Net Activity", LookAt:=xlPart).End(xlDown)
```

Now for the magic. Let's loop these bad boys, and do our comparison

```
Dim x as Integer
For x = 1 to rangeNames.finalValue
     'Let's do a quick check to make sure we haven't missed a range
     If (recRanges(x) Is Nothing) Or (balRanges(x) Is Nothing) Then
          MsgBox "Error on the rangeNames Enum with value " + CStr(x) + "."
          Exit Sub
     End If
     'I am just assuming you want your OK/Difference at the following range.
     'You may have to adjust it if you want it elsewhere
     Dim resultRange as Range
     Set resultRange = recRanges(x).Offset(1)
     If recRanges(x) = balRanges(x) Then
          resultRange.Value = "OK"
          resultRange.Interior.Color = RGB(0,255,0)
     Else
          resultRange.Value = "Difference"
          resultRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255,0,0)
     End If
Next x
```

**EDIT IN RESPONSE TO QUESTION IN COMMENTS**

If one of the values is the negative of the other, there are two ways to handle that. If none of the other comparisons could be the exact negative, then you'd simply replace this line

```
If recRanges(x) = balRanges(x) Then
```

With this

```
If Abs(recRanges(x)) = Abs(balRanges(x)) Then
```

`Abs()` is just the absolute value function; it ignores negative signs. If there is the possibility of one of the recRanges and balRanges being the additive inverse of each other, then yes you'd have to set up an `IF` statement.

```
 If x = rangeNames.TB2 Then
      'Let's make sure recRanges and balRanges contain a number
      If ((IsNumeric(recRanges(x).Value) = False) Or _
          (IsNumeric(balRanges(x).Value) = False)) Then
           MsgBox "Error in TB2 ranges, either the recRange or balRange is not a number."
           Exit Sub
      End If
      If recRanges(x).Value = (-1 * CDbl(balRanges(x).Value)) Then
           resultRange.Value = "OK"
           resultRange.Interior.Color = RGB(0,255,0)
      Else
           resultRange.Value = "Difference"
           resultRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255,0,0)          
      End If
 Else
      If recRanges(x) = balRanges(x) Then
           resultRange.Value = "OK"
           resultRange.Interior.Color = RGB(0,255,0)
      Else
           resultRange.Value = "Difference"
           resultRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255,0,0)
      End If
 End If
```

Comment: Thank you for the conserted effort.  This is my first time working with enumerated so I'm not sure what I need to do to execute.  Do I need to change my sub as a private or public sub or do I need to call something

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. Treat your Enum definition like its a new function or sub. You should literally just be able to paste the `Public Enum ... End Enum` I have above or below your existing Sub. I usually use `Public Enum ... End Enum`. I haven't run into any problems defining the Enum as public yet.

Comment: I apologize but I'm not sure the order of operation.  I'm assuming I'm placing the Public Enum...End Enum at the beginning of the module then I should have a sub below it and I will place the definition of the ranges and the loop.  I'm getting an error 'sub or function' not defined when it is reading through the setting the different ranges.  Everything I have learned has been through my own investigation so things like this will come up and I'm not sure where to proceed.

Comment: No need to apologize, this is how everyone learns. Plus I still haven't been clear. Let's try this. In your module paste the `Public Enum...End Enum`. Then paste your original `Sub RecValidation` into the module underneath it. The, delete everything within that `Sub` after `'Set up Range variables for the grandtotals for each column with amounts on recon template that come from supporting docs` except for `End Sub`. Finally, paste in the rest of the code blocks I have suggested. So everything except the `Enum` will reside within the `Sub`.

Comment: The issue was changing recRange to recRanges on the lines where the ranges are being set.  The new issue is that a syntax error appeared on the MsgBox line

Comment: That's because there was an error in that line. I have fixed it. I had forgotten to put a `+` between `CStr(x)` and `"."`. `CStr()` is a function that changes non string datatypes, like integer and double, into strings.

Comment: Thanks DBD!  I was able to make the changes and the code works perfectly along with the rest of my sub modules on my project.  What do you think will need to be changed if the TB2 total is a negative on the main reconciliation sheet but a positive amount on the supporting documentation tab?  Will the IF statement have to change from equals to "A - B = 0"?

Comment: No problem. I added an edit to the main that describes a couple of ways to deal with the problem. If I read you right, `A-B=0` is not the logic you are looking for. You would want `A+B=0`. But maybe I just misunderstood what you were saying.

Comment: The Absolute logic works the best.  I've tested it with several different results and I got what I expected.  I'm going to read up on the link you gave me for Enum and research some of the logic you provided for me to learn.  Thank you very much for the insight.

Comment: I can't vote on up your answer because I don't have the reputation yet but it deserves a vote up

Comment: No worries, I like this stuff. I hope it helps you write better code in the future